# Is *raises the need for* a valid and meaningful phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

I wanted to use the phrase "*This raises the need for ...*". A simple google search brought many results, most of which were either publications by non-native speakers or english pages of foreign websites. I was wondering if this is a common or correct phrase to use. I want to convey the meaning of "*This gives rise to a need for...*", but the juxtaposition of words seems weird to me.

Comment: It helps if you give a whole sentence, otherwise it is easy to give irrelevant answers to what you are looking for. You could also provide a link where these phrases are used.

Comment: I am not confident enough of my linguistic intuitions on this matter, so I am not posting this as an answer, but to my ear *raises the need for* is suited only to the cases where the causal connection is fairly direct, while *gives rise to the need for* can be used when the connection is indirect and works in combination with other causal factors. I would thus be inclined to say 'the current pandemic raises the need for face masks', but 'the current pandemic gives rise to the need for food delivery services'.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that "This raises the need for" is correct but it can be understood as "This **increases** the need for" or "This **creates** the need for". "This gives rise to a need for...", solves the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Blade,

I think you're fine here. *"This raises the need for"* seems perfectly natural to me. "*This gives rise to a need for*" is also grammatically correct, although I'll admit, it sounded strange to me as well.

Google's Ngram viewer is far better for checking these types of things than a straight Google search because, among other things, you can limit it to English books. Have a look [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=This%20raises%20the%20need%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2004&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThis%20raises%20the%20need%20for%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CThis%20raises%20the%20need%20for%3B%2Cc0) for the usage and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22this%20raises%20the%20need%20for%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2004,cd_max:2004&lr=lang_en) for examples in literature.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Google Ngrams show that *raises the need for* is at least comparable in idiomaticity with *gives/gave/will give/have given rise to a need for* (and *the need for*). We have to take into account that there are more variants hidden in the 'rise to a/the need for' data.

[image]

This is as I would have estimated; 'This gives rise to a/the need for...' sound fine to my ears. Looking at the the first 30 results in a Google search for "gives rise to a need for" yields no worrying examples, and mainly examples from businesses / institutions / legislatures in the US and UK.

And 'This raises the need for ...' is, although as you are picking up a slightly odd usage of 'raise' (while 'give rise to' is a familiar idiom), in fairly common use. Again, Google results for a search for the 5-word string are nearly (if not totally) entirely of well-written examples from institutions etc.

As Greybeard points out though, it introduces ambiguity. But, looking at examples on the internet, the 'gives rise to' rather than the 'increases' sense of 'raise' seems by far the more common.

Comment: Do I take it as a compliment that you haven't given this comment under the other answers to date? // I've done a reasonable sampling of the results of Google searches. OP seems to have very different search parameters.